# How to get the 'Value' Attriibute from the Controller MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I'm trying to get the value of my buttons to make my code a bit more dynamic rather than hard coded.

Currently I have it passing the 'name' attribute to the controller and checking if the name matches the value to determine where to link the user.

Here's the buttons:

```
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" name="cancelledResponse" value="Edit Quote">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" name="cancelledResponse" value="New Quote">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" name="cancelledResponse" value="PAY NOW">
```

And here's an example of how it's checking for it in the controller:

```
public ActionResult OrderCancelledSendLink(OrderCancelledSendEmailViewModel viewModel, string cancelledResponse)
    {
                if (cancelledResponse == "Edit Quote")
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("InsuredDetails", new { uid = order.OrderUid });
                }
    }
```

Any ideas on how to change this from hard coding the string check, it might cause some issues in the future if anyone wants to change the value of the buttons.

Comment: How about just giving the buttons different names?

Comment: Yeah had that before but changed it to this, that way I have to pass too many arguments into the Action, makes it look ugly to me. But if it has be be ugly or harder to maintain then I guess I'll choose ugly.